# Could not read from remote repository - Github

Tags: git, github, git-push

estoy tratando de subir un proyecto a github

al aplicar el ultimo comando _>  `git push -u origin main` me muestra este error:

```
$ git push -u origin main
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '[140.82.112.35]:443' to the list of known hosts.
git@ssh.github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

tienen idea de a que se debe??

Comment: Qué otros comandos has usado? Antes del push, que otros pasos has ejecutado. Has creado el repositorio en GitHub?

Comment: Haz un ```git remote``` para saber si esta conectado a tu repositorio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que muestras en la pregunta, pareciera como si el remote lo tuvieras configurado por SSH. Ese error se debe a que no tienes una llave SSH configurada en tu máquina o la llave que tienes no tiene permisos para acceder al repositorio remoto.

Puedes utilizar el siguiente enlace para Generar una nueva clave SSH en tu máquina y posteriormente debes registrarla en la plataforma de tu repositorio remoto:

[Generar una nueva clave SSH](https://docs.github.com/es/github/authenticating-to-github/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent)

De igual forma te recomiendo también intentar cambiar la URL de tu remote por una a través de HTTP. Puedes utilizar este comando:

```
git remote set-url origin https://URL/DEL/REPOSITORIO.git
```